# What is the meaning of 'at a near run'?

Tags: meaning-in-context

He ascended the peak in 3 hours, taking the final moderate pitch at a near run.

I don't understand "taking the final moderate pitch at a near run".

Can somebody help me out?

Answer (score 2):

The pitch is the slope of the mountain, which is (in this case) moderate at the top.  The person ascending covers this stretch "at a near run," i.e., almost running.

Comment: Fixed already. . .

Comment: You can strengthen this answer by including a definition of *pitch*, and explaining that the pitch refers to the angle.  You could also include an example.